# Find leaf nodes of the tree in SQL Sever

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

This is the schema of my table:

```
Create Table OBJECT_TREE 
( PARENT_ID     int, 
CHILD_ID    int )
```

The sample data in that table looks like this:

```
PARENT_ID   CHILD_ID
---------------------
1             2
2             3
2             4
2             5
3             6
3             7
4             8
4             9

1 ________2________3_______6
                   |       |
                   |       |______7
                   |
                   |
                   |______4_______8
                   |              |
                   |              |______9
                   |
                   |
                   |______5
```

A SQL Server stored procedure should return all objects "down" in the hierarchy of a given node (all down hierarchy objects of node 2 are 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

Please help to find the leaf nodes of the tree.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I don't think your graph matches your table data? Very cool question though and excellent answer from @wildplasser

Answer (score 7):

Fortunately this is one of the few cases where you *dont* need recursion:

```
SELECT DISTINCT child_id
FROM object_tree ot
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM object_tree nx
    WHERE nx.parent_id = ot.child_id
    );
```

Comment: How can we get only leaves (objects with no children)  
EX: of node 2 are 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

Answer (score 1):

This query will returns all leaf node those are not have chield nodes.

```
 SELECT  ot.child_id
FROM object_tree ot
left join object_tree nx on  nx.parent_id = ot.child_id
where nx. parent_id is null
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.